# If $g(h(x))=x$ when does $f(x)=g(f(h(x))$ imply $f(x)=cx$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

For example

$$f(x)=2f(\frac{x}{2})$$

implies $f(x)=cx$ under what condition? For example, is continuity required for $f(x)$,$g(x)$,$h(x)$ all or some of them?

Obviously, we can construct $f(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{f(x)}{2}$ starting from some value at $f(1)$. However, if the function does not behave nicely around $1$, this may create a hectic behavior around $0$ too.

If we set, for example, continuity as required is there any restriction over $g(x)$ or $h(x)$, apart from those obvious, when $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ are not defined somewhere, which is acceptable?

Are all other solutions necessarily not continuous functions?

Another example $f(x)=\ln(f(e^x))$ apart from obvious requirement that $f(x)$ is not negative, has a solution $f(x)=x$ and... is there any other comparable?

Comment: Can you define properly the functional equation you want to solve?

Comment: @Raito All of them that are of the same type as $f(x)=\ln(f(e^x))$ where $\ln(e^x)=x$. Replace $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$ with whatever function $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ so that $g(h(x))=x$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g(h(x))=x$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and suppose $h(x)$ is not of the form $cx$, for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

Then lettting $f=h$, we get
$$g(f(h(x))) = g(h(h(x))) = h(x) = f(x)$$
so $f$ satisfies the specified identity, but $f(x)$ is not of the form $cx$, where $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

More generally, if $k$ is any function such that $k\circ h=h\circ k$, then letting $f=h\circ k$, we get
$$g(f(h(x))) = g(h(k(h(x))))=k(h(x))=h(k(x))= f(x)$$

In particular, to satisfy the identity
$$f(x)=\ln(f(e^x))$$
with a function other than $f(x)=x$, you can take $f(x)$ to be any of
$$\ln(x),\;\;\;\ln(\ln(x)),\;\;\;\ln(\ln(\ln(x))),\;\;.\;\;.\;\;.$$

Comment: very clean and clear

Comment: Of course it does not force. That is the point. The question is under what condition it does force $f=x$.

Comment: Pretty much never.